# how to generate a QR Code for array of data like json array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, qr-code

I have used a simple QR code:
https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode
but I think it doesn't support an array of objects or even a simple array...

```
  <div class="mb-3">
        {!! QrCode::encoding('UTF-8')->size(150)->generate($firstName); !!}
    </div>
```

how can I add array of data, or array of objects in QR Code with Laravel,, thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="mb-3">
   {!! QrCode::encoding('UTF-8')->size(150)->generate('['.$firstName.', '.$lastName.', '.$email.']'); !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.